# Como capturar sons no Android Studio?

Tags: android

Tudo bem??

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma função no Android Studio para capturar os sons do ambiente pelo microfone do celular. Estou tentando implementar uma função de comando de voz sem ser necessário clicar em algum botão.

Comment: oi, bem vindo, o que você já tentou fazer? existem milhares de exemplos na internet sobre isso, importe e utilize o pacote `android.media.AudioRecord;` essa função permite gravar ...

Comment: Então, no meu app eu estou utilizando o speech to text para reconhecer comandos por voz, mas é necessário ficar clicando em um Button toda vez, por conta disso eu queria uma função que fosse capaz de ficar capturando o áudio e reconhecer quando um comando é falado.